# Translate mfc outlookbar dialog strings

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC outlookbar implemenated.There is dialog appears on clicking outlooktab bar tab(Navigation pane option).I want to localize the dialog string because i think its a MFC provided dialog so on localization of application this dialog's string is not getting localized.

Answer (score 1):

You need your own localization of the MFC resources.

In VS-2013 for example this is a MFC120xxx.DLL, ENU for english, DEU for German, TRK for turkish, etc.

The MFC comes only with a few translations.

If you use static resources you need to create your own translation in the include folders of the MFC here (i.e. turkish):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\l.trk

Sample folder is for VS-2013.

I used make files from an older VS-Version to create my own MFC language resource files. They still work with VS-2010 and later.

Comment: I am using my own localization for all the languages.All of my dialog's strings are getting localize dynamically but this one is the outlookbar's default dialog.I am not able to find its static key or don't know any of its method can be override or not.I got similar thing implemented in VB but not in MFC.Adding link for reference.I need similar thing in VC++(MFC)    http://www.codejock.com/support/articles/com/shortcutbar/sb_1.asp

Comment: All data of the resources of the MFC are here C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio VER\VC\atlmfc\include\l.xxx

Comment: I cannot find the resources of the dialog in given path.Can you please explain in details.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks,I am able to find the resources of the dialog in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio VER\VC\atlmfc\include\l.xxx.I just tried using SetThreadLocale(lang id) to pick the resources from these l.xxx but still not getting the translated dialog.

Comment: So you included all the resources from this languages with the correct language ID into your project?

Comment: Yes.I have tested with lang id 1031 which is for germany corresponds to l.deu